# Not detecting changes upon refresh using tbroyers gwt-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I have an issue with my current setup that doesn't detect changes upon refreshing a page. It works if I manually trigger the compilation with the bookmark, but I don't like having to do this every single time I make a change.

Here is my current setup:

- IntellijIDEA 2017.2.1
- Maven
- Tomcat (using IntellijIDEA run configuration)
- GWT 2.8.2

Whole pom.xml can be found here: https://gist.github.com/BenDol/75c9299b20cb285a8f57a89aa00bf28e

Parent pom.xml: https://gist.github.com/BenDol/6524ad17de7977f54a496a93a26aabf0

gwt-maven-plugin setup:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${gwt-maven-plugin.version}</version>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <configuration>
    <moduleName>com.insclix.mvc.App</moduleName>
    <style>OBFUSCATED</style>
    <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
    <sourceLevel>${java.version}</sourceLevel>
    <jvmArgs>
      <jvmArg>${argLine}</jvmArg>
      <jvmArg>-Xmx1g</jvmArg>
      <jvmArg>-Xms1g</jvmArg>
      <jvmArg>-XX:CompileThreshold=7000</jvmArg>
      <jvmArg>-Derrai.dev.context=${errai.dev.context}</jvmArg>
      <jvmArg>-Derrai.client.local.class.pattern=${errai.client.class.pattern}</jvmArg>
      <jvmArg>${profileLine}</jvmArg>
    </jvmArgs>
    <optimize>9</optimize>
    <compilerArgs>
      <arg>-compileReport</arg>
      <arg>-XcompilerMetrics</arg>
    </compilerArgs>
    <warDir>${webappDirectory}</warDir>
    <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
    <classpathScope>compile+runtime</classpathScope>
    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
        <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

If anyone has any suggestions to help me figure this out, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for taking the time to read through this post.

Regards,
Ben

Comment: It's not clear how you're launching dev mode: `gwt:devmode`, `gwt:codeserver`, something else?

Comment: Ah yea forgot to mention that, gwt:codeserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [`launcherDir`](https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/codeserver-mojo.html#launcherDir) to get compile-on-load.

You seem to have a mix of configuration for Mojo's plugin and mine, you should probably clean that up and re-read the docs to sort them up.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Are you able to help me understand where I need to point the launchDir in my current set up? I have read its documentation and it doesn't make clear where I am suppose to point this in the case of my particular set up. Thanks for the help, most appreciated.

Comment: You need to point it to the director served by Tomcat (maybe simply `${webappDirectory}`)